# Core Data ordeal

Tags: ios, swift, oop, core-data

A few weeks ago, I decided to learn Core Data for my new project and apply it to my entire model. There was a steep learning curve, but eventually I got familiar with the stack and I'm now rather comfortable with at least the basic concepts and the few common pitfalls such as thread concurrency.

I have to say, the first few weeks after getting comfortable where pretty amazing. `NSFetchedResultsController` give you a good way to communicate between my model and my controllers. However the more I use Core Data, the more annoying it gets.

As a concrete example, my app fetches a few pieces of data from my server (the posts) which appear in a feed. Each post has an owner, of class `User`, which I also fetch from the server. Now, Core Data has been great for managing the realtionship between a post and a user. The relationship is updated automatically and getting the post's origin is as simple as calling `post.owner`. However, there are also inconveniences:

1.**Core Data forces objects to the disk that I do not want forced to the disk**. This is probably the main issue. With the posts, I do not want them to be forced to disk, and would rather make calls to the server again. Why? Because the more posts I store persistently, the more housekeeping there is to do. A post can be edited, deleted, flagged, etc... and keeping those posts locally means having to plan updates.

2.**Having to constantly worry about concurrency of contexts, objects and the likes**. I wrote an object factory that always returns objects on the right thread and the right context, but even then bugs occur here and there, which quickly becomes frustrating.

3.**Decreased performance**. Perhaps the least important one at this point, going from cached objects to Core Data has taken a (barely noticeable) toll on the performance of my application (most notably the feed).

So what are your recommendations regarding Core Data? Would you suggest a different approach to Core Data?

I was thinking of a hybrid caching + Core Data where I store the information I will actually use many times (such as users) persistently and then use the RAM for things like posts, or simply creating posts without an `NSManagedContext`. Input welcome!

Comment: Try  in-memory store ?

Answer (score 1):

> Core Data forces objects to the disk that I do not want forced to the disk.

It does no such thing. If you don't want to save your `Post` objects to the persistent store, don't put them in Core Data and don't make them managed objects. Your `User` object can have a `posts` property even if the `Post` object is not managed by Core Data. Managed objects can have properties of any type, not only to other managed objects.

> Having to constantly worry about concurrency of contexts, objects and the likes.

Concurrency is complex no matter how you model your data. It's a fundamentally complex problem. You're encountering it with Core Data because you're using Core Data. If you use something else, you'll deal with it there.

> Decreased performance.

"Product" menu --> "Analyze" and run Instruments to find out why. There's no reason this should happen, and you have the tools to discover what's actually going on.